# Why is my 206 (Partial Content) response being saved instead of invoking further requests?

Tags: download, http-headers

I'm trying to serve files in chunks from an Azure Function. In my test/development case I have a 54-byte file, and I'm responding in chunks of 10 bytes.

What I expected is that the browser would make 6 requests in total, then save a 54-byte file.

What happens is that 1 request is made and a 10-byte file is saved.

This is what I can see in the browser's *Network* tab:

> HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
> Content-Length: 10
> Content-Type: text/xml
> Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2024 17:27:43 GMT
> Server: Kestrel
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
> Cache-Control: no-store
> Content-Range: bytes 0-9/54
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xml

What have I done wrong, or neglected to do? Is there a header missing?

How can I 'invite' the browser to make subsequent requests to download the entire contents of the file?